# Error while trying to run jetty from ant: "failed to create task or type jetty.run"

Tags: ant, jetty, jetty-8

I receive the following error:

```
Buildfile: ...\jetty.xml
jetty.run:

BUILD FAILED
...\jetty.xml:29: Problem: failed to create task or type jetty.run
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.

Total time: 617 milliseconds
```

when running `ant jetty.run` in this:

```
<path id="jetty.plugin.classpath">
    <fileset dir="./lib/jetty" includes="*.jar" />
</path>

<taskdef classpathref="jetty.plugin.classpath" resource="tasks.properties" loaderref="jetty.loader" />
<typedef name="selectChannelConnector" classname="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector" classpathref="jetty.plugin.classpath" loaderref="jetty.loader" />

<pathconvert property="classpathProp" refid="jetty.plugin.classpath" />
<target name="echo">
    <echo>Classpath is ${classpathProp}</echo>
</target>

<target name="jetty-run">
    <jetty>
        <connectors>
            <selectChannelConnector port="8080" />
        </connectors>
    </jetty>
</target>

<target name="jetty.run">
    <jetty.run stopPort="8080" stopKey="stopKey123">
    </jetty.run>
</target>

<target name="jetty.stop">
    <jetty.stop stopPort="8080" stopKey="stopKey123" stopWait="10" />
</target>
```

The above target (jetty.run) is identical in syntax to the documentation [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.10.v20150310/ant-and-jetty.html) (see/search for **stopping**).  Why is `jetty.run` not working, where as `jetty-run` is?

`jetty-run` output:

```
Buildfile: ...\jetty.xml
jetty-run:
    [jetty] Configuring Jetty for project: system-tests
    [jetty] 2015-04-22 17:16:46.603:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.16.v20140903
    [jetty] 2015-04-22 17:16:46.728:WARN:oejsh.RequestLogHandler:!RequestLog
    [jetty] 2015-04-22 17:16:46.884:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

Though the [Jetty 9 docs](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.10.v20150310/ant-and-jetty.html) use jetty.run and jetty.stop, this [guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Use_Jetty_with_Ant) does not.  It is clear that it has to do with `<jetty.run ...>` vs `<jetty ...>`, but I'm currently at a loss to explain why and unable to get `<jetty.run ...>` and `<jetty.stop ...>` to work.

The classpath:

```
[echo] Classpath is 
...\com.sun.el-2.2.0.v201108011116.jar
...\javax.activation-1.1.0.v201105071233.jar
...\javax.annotation-1.1.0.v201108011116.jar
...\javax.el-2.2.0.v201108011116.jar
...\javax.mail.glassfish-1.4.1.v201005082020.jar
...\javax.servlet.jsp-2.2.0.v201112011158.jar
...\javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.0.v201105211821.jar
...\javax.transaction-1.1.1.v201105210645.jar
...\jetty-ajp-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-annotations-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-ant-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-client-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-continuation-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-deploy-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-http-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-io-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-jmx-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-jndi-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-monitor-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-overlay-deployer-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-plus-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-policy-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-rewrite-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-security-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-servlets-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-webapp-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-websocket-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\jetty-xml-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\org.apache.jasper.glassfish-2.2.2.v201112011158.jar
...\org.apache.taglibs.standard.glassfish-1.2.0.v201112081803.jar
...\org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.7.1.jar
...\org.objectweb.asm-3.1.0.v200803061910.jar
...\servlet-api-3.0.jar
...\spdy-core-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\spdy-jetty-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
...\spdy-jetty-http-8.1.16.v20140903.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `jetty.run` is not working in this case whereas `jetty-run` is because the task `<jetty.run ...` which the target `jetty.run` uses was added in version 9 of the jetty-ant task, as stated by the dev who added it ([see this jetty-dev mailing list msg](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-dev/msg02407.html)).

I tried version 9 of jetty with version 9 of jetty-ant and the target `jetty.run` worked as expected.  I also tried jetty 9 with jetty-ant 8, but got this:

```
BUILD FAILED
...\build.xml:9: typedef class org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector cannot be found
```